# socket.accept accepts 2 connections

Tags: python, sockets

I have a server\client communication organized via socket library in python.

There are a lot of materials online how to use it and it seems to be pretty straightforward [ref 1](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/06/python-socket-network-programming/).

There is always a while True loop that keeps accepting connections and my understanding is that it will accept only one at a time, service it and go to the next one in the queue. The depth of the queue is defined by socket.listen(N) where N is the depth.

I create the socket server.

```
self.sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
self.sock.bind(('', port)) 
self.sock.listen(10)
self.socket_port = port
```

I have a while True loop that waits for the socket connection to come

```
def run_socket(self):
        '''
        creates a separete thread for server_thread function
        '''
        start_new_thread(self.server_thread,())
def server_thread(self):
    self.is_running = True
    self.update_CAS()
    while self.is_running:
        self.client, self.addr = self.sock.accept()
        info( 'Client has connected: %r %r' % (self.client, self.addr ))
        ##Here I have code to service the incoming connection from the 
        ###client. The client closes connection when it receives the   
        ###response. THis section is not shown for simplicity.
```

So this works well. However, I have gotten cases when 2 clients have connected within several milliseconds apart, see below. The second client was serviced correctly but the first one wasn't because the socket was overwritten by the second one. It took input from the second client and

I need to have a server that can queue clients but will service only one client at a time.

```
2018-06-08 13:17:37,838 INFO: Client has connected: <socket._socketobject object at 0x084B0E68> ('128.231.5.169', 60915)
2018-06-08 13:17:37,838 INFO: input from the client: [4, [1000, 4000]] with client, addr = (<socket._socketobject object at 0x084B0E68>,('128.231.5.169', 60915))
2018-06-08 13:17:37,854 INFO: checking buffer status True, nan
2018-06-08 13:17:37,854 DEBUG: Reply has been generated and sent back
2018-06-08 13:17:39,104 INFO: Client has connected: <socket._socketobject object at 0x084B0F80> ('128.231.5.59', 51292)
2018-06-08 13:17:39,118 INFO: Client has connected: <socket._socketobject object at 0x084B0E68> ('128.231.5.169', 60916)
2018-06-08 13:17:39,134 INFO: input from the client: [4, [1000, 4000]] with client, addr = (<socket._socketobject object at 0x084B0E68>,('128.231.5.169', 60916))
2018-06-08 13:17:39,134 INFO: checking buffer status True, nan
2018-06-08 13:17:39,134 DEBUG: Reply has been generated and sent back
2018-06-08 13:17:39,165 INFO: input from the client: [4, [2000, 5000]] with client, addr = (<socket._socketobject object at 0x084B0E68>,('128.231.5.169', 60916))
2018-06-08 13:17:39,165 INFO: checking buffer status True, nan
2018-06-08 13:17:39,165 DEBUG: Reply has been generated and sent back
2018-06-08 13:17:40,400 INFO: Client has connected: <socket._socketobject object at 0x084B0DF8> ('128.231.5.169', 60917)
2018-06-08 13:17:40,415 INFO: input from the client: [4, [1000, 4000]] with client, addr = (<socket._socketobject object at 0x084B0DF8>,('128.231.5.169', 60917))
```

I know that it takes ~ 70 - 100 ms to service one client:

```
2018-06-07 22:50:59,750 INFO: Client has connected: <socket._socketobject object at 0x0760DE68> ('128.231.5.82', 54184)
2018-06-07 22:50:59,765 INFO: input from the client: [4, [1000, 3000]]
2018-06-07 22:50:59,769 DEBUG: Reply has been generated and sent back
2018-06-07 22:50:59,772 INFO: true checking buffer status 0.0
2018-06-07 22:50:59,821 DEBUG: checking buffer status 28.375206497045973
```

This shouldn't have happened. Am I correct?

I have tested it with a simple code server\client:

```
    """
Simple SOCKET server for testing\learning purposes
"""

import socket

sock = socket.socket()
port = 2033
sock.bind(('',port))
sock.listen(5)

while True:
    client, adrr = sock.accept()
    print('Got connection from ' , adrr)
    x = raw_input('keyboard input')
    client.send('Connection Received %r' % x)
    client.close()
```

and client

```
# Import socket module
import socket               

def connection():
    # Create a socket object
    s = socket.socket()         

    # Define the port on which you want to connect
    port = 2033         

    # connect to the server on local computer
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', port))

    # receive data from the server
    print s.recv(1024)
    # close the connection
    s.close()
```

Client:

```
>>> connection();connection();
Connection Received '1'
Connection Received '2'
>>>
```

Server:

```
('Got connection from ', ('127.0.0.1', 49436))
keyboard input:1
('Got connection from ', ('127.0.0.1', 49437))
keyboard input:2
```

I guess the big question is: What is going on? Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand your question. In `server_thread`, are you saying that you expect the part after the `accept` call to take longer than several milliseconds? When I run your client/server example it works as I expect. Maybe you could clarify what you are expecting and how this is behaving differently.

Comment: FamousJameous: Yes, the servicing of the incoming connection does take more than several milliseconds. The new connection shouldn't have been created before the end of the while loop. This is illustrated in the simple example at the end. The server waits for the first connection to be served and only after that moves to the second one. 
"Maybe you could clarify what you are expecting and how this is behaving differently" - it should not accept the second connection from the client if the first one hasn't been serviced yet. However, the server did.

Comment: You seem to have client and server backwards in the simpler example.

Comment: I don't see anything in this question that indicates that it's not processing connections sequentially.

Comment: Barmar: The socket on the server side will server only one connection at a time. But the second client connected before the first one was serviced.

Comment: Where does it say that? It looks like it took 10 ms to service the first client, then the second client connected.

Comment: This code does the processing sequentially, end of story. In order to do parallel or asynchronous processing in Python, you'd have to use special modules or write a ton of code implementing that yourself. Since your code lacks all of that and is essentially a simple loop, it only does sequential processing. That your program can serve a client very quickly is perfectly fine. After all, these are two simple programs executed by computers, and computers are actually _extremely_ fast.

Comment: ForceBru: That is entire idea. But I accepted another connection before the first one was serviced. Actually, both connections were serviced simultaneously. (edited the question)

Comment: @Valentyn, this means that you're running this code in multiple threads. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @ForceBru, I made edits to the question. It is probably confusing what I am showing in the shell with debug and info. I have one thread that takes care of the while True loop. But sometimes I get two connections within the time that is less the time needed to service one of them. This results in a complete mess in variables. It literally looks like the second socket.accept overwrites the first one. I checked my full code i don't have nested thread or anything.

Comment: @Valentyn, you literally start a new thread with `start_new_thread(self.server_thread,())`.

Comment: @ForceBru, and I do it once. run_socket command doesn't take care of one socket connection. it just to start the thread once. The name is probably misleading. but you were totally right when pointed on threading. I just found out that I had indeed nested threads. I had two threads with two while loops running. Thanks, everyone for questions and comments!